# What is the difference between a theological investigation and a Biblical theology

Tags: biblical-theology

I know that this may seem like a dumb question but I still cannot list the differences. Someone asked me whether Dispensationalism is a theological investigation or a Biblical theology and I'm not sure what to answer because I dont know what are they. Can anyone please help me out here? It would be a great help!

Comment: I'm not aware of "theological investigation" being a formal term... if you mean what the regular combination of those words would mean then like most theological systems it would probably qualify, but that doesn't mean it wouldn't also be a system of Biblical Theology.

Comment: So is there a difference between a theological system and Biblical theology?

Comment: Sure. Not all theological systems concern progressive revelation.

Comment: If possible, ask the person to state how he/she sees the difference. Is the person asking if Dispensationalism is dubious doctrine vs whether it can be proven conclusively by Biblical Theology (investigation of Scripture)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of "theological investigation" as a formal process, but taking the various words at face value I would interpret them as follows:

1. **Theology** is the study of God. We do theology when we think about God, who he is, what he does, his relationship with creation. This is true whatever conclusions we may reach. The Christian may think that God exists and is good. The atheist may think that God does not exist, or that if he exists he is not good. Both of those thoughts are theological in nature.
2. I would define a **theological investigation** informally as a process of exploring what I or another person or group believes about God. For example I may wonder what a typical Buddhist believes about God, so I might spend time researching that question. This would constitute a theological investigation.
3. **Biblical theology** is a subset of theology. It considers the relationship between God and the Bible. If we take the Bible as our starting point, what do we learn about God? In what ways is God the author or inspirer of the Bible? Note that once more there is no one necessary content of Biblical theology. The Christian and the atheist may have different opinions over the God who is revealed in those pages. And even between Christians there are various Biblical theologies.
4. So in summary I would answer the OP by describing the relationship between theological investigation and Biblical theology as one of overlap. For example, a theological investigation into the Bible will result in some form of Biblical theology. But it is also possible to conduct a theological investigation into other world views, and such an investigation would result in a non biblical theology.

Comment: This answer is stated as your own opinion, without any citations or references.

Comment: Expressions such as "_I would interpret_", "_I would define_", and ""I would answer_" are a good way of getting downvotes, regardless of the merits of the actual answer.  The best answers are worded as if they were written in an encyclopedia or text book.  And as Nigel suggests, support your facts with references.

Comment: An interesting response. My starting point was that as far as I know "theological investigation" is not a formal term with a definition that one will find in reference books. If you look at curious danni's comment on the OP you will see I'm not the only one who thinks this. So I had to start by defining what I personally understood the term to mean if I was going to say anything at all. If that's wrong, others are welcome to point to the scholarly references that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the difference between a theological investigation and a Biblical theology**

A theological investigation is the study of the doctrines or beliefs as taught by a given religion or denomination or other individuals or groups. And the scriptures which constituted as fitting to such beliefs.

For example, you may be reading   Titus 2:13.  The NIV and the ESV translators prefer to see Paul referring to Jesus as God, and accordingly shift the possessive pronoun "our" to a position before  "God" thus drawing the two phrases completely together.  This may fit what you already believe and be happy with it.

Titus 2:13 (NIV)

> 13 "While we wait for the blessed hope—the appearing of the glory of
>   our great God and Savior, Jesus Christ,

Titus 2:13  (ESV)

> 13 "Waiting for our blessed hope, the appearing of the glory of our
>   great God and Savior Jesus Christ,

However, if you are reading NABRE or the KJV  below, you will notice that those translators understand Paul to refer to both God and Jesus Christ as two separate individuals. Again this may fit, what you already believe and be happy with it.

Titus 2:13  (NABRE)

> 13 "As we await the blessed hope, the appearance of the glory of the
>   great God and of our savior Jesus Christ,"

Titus 2:13 King James Version (KJV)

> 13 "Looking for that blessed hope, and the glorious appearing of the
>   great God and our Saviour Jesus Christ;"

Biblical theology, however, means that you want to find what God's Word itself says, so when faced with such ambiguous passages, you look for similar passages for comparison of expression, on the same subject and so help to clarify the possible meaning of the words that are being translated.

For example:

The closest parallels to Titus 2:13 are Titus 1:4 and  2 Thessalonians 1:12  In Titus 2:13 the phrase "Savior of us" is before Christ Jesus and in Titus 1:4 "our Savior" switches position it is after "our Savior". The variations in the two verses is entirely incidental.

Titus 2:13 WHNU

tou       Megalou Theou    kai                 Soteros       hemon   Xristou Iesou

of the   great     God  and  (of the)              Savior    of us     Christ Jesus.

Titus 1:4  WHNU

from   God    the Father   and    Christ Jesus         our Savior.                                                                               apo   Theou      Patros    kai    Xristou Iesou  tou Soteros hemon

2 Thessalonians 1:12 WHNU

tou         theou hemon   kai      kuriou Iesou Chistou
of    our     God         and the Lord    Jesus Christ.

**The grammatical structure in all verses is the same making it doubtful that they should be translated in different ways.  See how the NIV and the ESV render Titus 1:4 and 2 Thess.1:12 Both translations refer to God and Jesus as two separate individuals, but not so in Titus 2:13.**

Titus 1:4  (NIV)

> 4 To Titus, my true son in our common faith:  Grace and peace from God
>   the Father and Christ Jesus our Savior.

Titus 1:4  (ESV)

> 4 To Titus, my true child in a common faith: Grace and peace from God
>   the Father and Christ Jesus our Savior.

2 Thessalonians 1:12  (NIV)

> 12 We pray this so that the name of our Lord Jesus may be glorified in
>   you, and you in him, according to the grace of our God and the Lord
>   Jesus Christ.[a]

2 Thessalonians 1:12  (ESV)

> 12 so that the name of our Lord Jesus may be glorified in you, and you
>   in him, according to the grace of our God and the Lord Jesus Christ.

**References on grammar: From the book "Truth in Translation" by Jason David BeDuhn, an associate professor of religious studies at Northern Arizona University, in Flagstaff.**

Answer (score 0):

Although the phrase "theological investigation" is not a formal term with a definition in any theology book I know of, the OP does give an example of a person asking him whether *"Dispensationalism is a theological investigation or a Biblical theology"*. This question has been asked out of a desire to obtain help answering this other person. Sadly, this answer is nearly three years too late to help the OP, but it's offered anyway in case a similar question arises on Biblical Hermeneutics.

Take any theological or biblical topic, and lots of people over the centuries will have investigated it from a theological point of view. 'Theology' is a word meaning:

> "Study of, or system of religion; rational analysis of a religious
> faith". *The Concise Oxford Dictionary*, sixth ed. 1976

Clearly, then, any study of, or system of religious faith requires investigation. Hence, it requires a theological investigation.

However, when it comes to biblical theology, there are two distinct ways of viewing this. One is to investigate any biblical topic (as opposed to the theology of Hinduism or Druidism etc., Buddhism being more of a philosophy as no belief in any god is required.) The second way is to investigate in order to ascertain whether any claimed Christian belief is biblical, or unbiblical. This seems to be the view of the person asking the OP if Dispensationalism is biblical theology, or not.

The word 'dispensation'is rarely in modern translations of the Bible, but it is in the Authorised Version, it being quite an old-fashioned word that, in a religious sense means,

> "Ordering, management, esp. of the world by Providence; special
> dealing with Providence with community or person; religious system
> regarded as divinely ordained for a nation or period. (Mosaic,
> Christian, dispensation)." *(Ibid.)*

In the Authorised Version there is, for example, 1 Corinthians 9:17, "...a dispensation of the gospel is committed unto me", and Ephesians 1:10, "...in the dispensation of the fulness of times". However, the person asking the original question seems to have in mind a much more modern use of the word as has been applied in certain Protestant circles to matters of eschatology. Here is one example:

> "Dr. Vern Poythress says regarding dispensationalism (the form of
> dogmatic theology found in the Schofield Reference Bible footnotes)
> 'Within this movement the Scofield Reference Bible, in particular,
> contributed more than any other work to the spread of
> dispensationalism in the United States." Vern S. Poythress,
> *Understanding Dispensationalists,* 2nd edition, (Phillipsburg, PA, USA: Presbyterian and Reformed Publishing Company, 1994), pp.19-20. As quoted in The Trinitarian Bible Society quarterly journal Issue No. 566

That particular reference Bible is now called the *Schofield Study Bible* 1917 edition. Dr. Cyrus Ingerson Schofield was born 19 August 1843, and died in 1921. He interpreted the Bible to mean that it had seven dispensations (from the Garden of Eden through to a future Millennial era) and so he taught.

> "His definition is as follows: 'A dispensation is a period of time
> during which man is tested in respect of obedience to some specific
> revelation of the will of God.' ...For such extension and enumeration
> of dispensations, however, he gives no scriptural authority - for the
> simple reason that there is none to be given. Nor does he indicate the
> grounds upon which he bases the assertion that there are just seven:
> he merely says so, in his characteristic manner. If this is enough to
> convince you, no more need be said; but if you are disposed to
> scrutinize the idea, and to demand some kind of proof, you will not be
> easily satisfied..." *The Schofield Bibe - a candid examination** by
> Albertus Pieters, pp14-16, Telos Book Centre, Singapore 1955, ISBN
> 981-00-4066-0

The last two quotes demonstrate how some scholars in Protestant circles ***have made a theological investigation into whether the dispensationalism of fellow-Protestant Scofield is biblical theology, or not. And they have concluded that it is not biblical theology***, despite many claims by those supporting it that the Bible is full of it. **This demonstrates the difference between a theological investigation, and a claimed biblical theology.**

Comment: "Biblical Theology" should not be taken to refer to theology that aligns with the Bible, but instead the discipline that concerns progressive or canonical studies of theology in the Bible, as contrasted with (but not disconnected from) systematic theology. Dispensationalism is definitely a type of Biblical Theology, even if most of us think it is a poor schema for understanding the Bible.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I was careful to say that re. "biblical theology, there are two distinct ways of viewing this" but the person asking the original Q seemed to hold to the 2nd way: theology that aligns with the Bible, plus also asking about this with respect to Dispensationalism. That is why I answered as I did. I was not stating my own views but quoting others while providing an example of the difference asked for by the OP. Nobody has said that Dispensationalism is not a type of biblical theology!

Comment: Neither of your two ways is what "Biblical Theology" refers to as a discipline. But yes, I don't think the question asker is aware of that.